# Multiple headers datatables dynamic

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, header, codeigniter-3

I found a problem regarding DataTables. Previously I added Headers to DataTables Manually, like so:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="example" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
    <th>Header3</th>
    <th>Header4</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

For that it doesn't matter. But when I add the header name like this (via database), like this :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="example" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
   <? foreach ($kolom as $row) : ?>
    <th><? echo $row ?></th>
   <? endforeach; ?>
  </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

The result will create 2 stacked headers like so:

```
| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
```

The value from **$kolom** is an Array like this :

```
Array ( [0] => Header1 [1] => Header2 [2] => Header3 [3] => Header4 )
```

This is the script from jQuery i use :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable;
  dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [{
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                 }],
   "aoColumns": [
                 {data : "f1"},
                 {data : "f2"},
                 {data : "f3"},
                 {data : "f4"}
                ],
   "scrollCollapse": true,
   "fixedColumns": {
                    "left": 1
                   },
   'processing': true,
   'language': {
                 "loadingRecords": '&nbsp;',
                 "processing" : '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px;color:rgb(75, 183, 245);"></i>'
               },
   "scrollX": true,
  });
 });
</script>
```

I only want to show 1 header only.
Which error did I experience and which part should I fix?

Thanks, I hope I can find a solution here.

Comment: I don't see how that code would produce stacked headers. You're not using `<tr>` in your `<thead>` so all headers are in _one_ row

Comment: When I add <tr> it still shows 2 header lines.

Comment: Is jquery datatables creating the headers already? How do you init datatables? What is the resulting HTML code for that table?

Comment: I've added the javascript code in the post, please check it

Comment: If I do Inspect Element from browser, it shows that the first header that appears has class : dataTables_scrollHead. While the second header has a class: dataTables_scrollBody

Comment: Which version of datatables are you using ? I have tested your code and is working fine for me

Comment: im use version 1.10.16

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? The fact that you are seeing `dataTables_scrollHead` suggests you are using additional libraries not mentioned in your question - for example, [this one](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/scrolling.html) or something like that. It also means there may be some conflict between this additional library and whatever styling library you may be using. But the main point is: Without a [mre] there is a lot of guesswork, here.